# Magento 2 set block template in layout vs in block

Tags: magento2, module, blocks, template

There are two ways to set a blocks template. 
Either in the block using

```
$this->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::template.phtml');
```

or in layout

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\BlockName" name="myblock"template="Vendor_Module::template.phtml"/>
```

Which way would be the best way to set a blocks template or what are the advantages/disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefere setting template in layout, so it could be extended easily in other modules just using layout.

If you have to set template depending on a condition, you could do it programmatically in block, just think of extensibility by using a public function (so it could be extended by plugin)